# Take long / scroll screenshot in the browser for paywalled content

Tags: scrolling, screenshot

How do I take a scrolling screenshot of a long webpage inside a paywall?

Note the webpage requires log-in and purchase, which I already did.

In Firefox / Chrome, the `Print` button only gets me the currently visible part of the page.

I also tried [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1088551/370203), but as the comment below says, the website `also cut off the actual content not far beyond the visual cut off, which makes a big screenshot with only the visual part on the first screen available.

I'm open to command line tools / browser extensions / standalone tools.

Ideally, this needs to be a free / low-cost application.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to take a screenshot that includes a scrolling element within a web page in Firefox?](https://superuser.com/questions/1088537/how-to-take-a-screenshot-that-includes-a-scrolling-element-within-a-web-page-in) Also https://superuser.com/questions/1250417/how-to-take-a-screenshot-of-an-entire-scroll-element?rq=1

Comment: Note that most paywalls will not just project a fading element on top of the content, but also cut off the actual content not far beyond the visual cut off, to prevent you from being able to do the above.

Comment: i'm trying a freeware (available only on Windows) called [PicPick](https://picpick.app/en/). It does scroll down and take screenshots, which automates but is slow (the page is very long). it would be great if the "Save to PDF" button works.

Comment: Check out ShareX. It's freeware with a good scrolling-capture option.

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks but no the paywalled website cut off the actual content. please see the edited question.

Comment: @XoXo You do realise that the cutting off part is by design right? Trying to bypass a paywall is likely breaking laws, the assisting of which I assume is at the very least frowned upon at SU.

Comment: @MiG thanks for bringing up the legal side of it. i agree to have the question marked as duplicate.

Comment: related reading: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/78757/legality-of-avoiding-paywalls